# Phonegap android apk splash not working

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build

Phonegap android apk splash not working.

We have added splash image inside these folders:

```
platform/android/res/drawable-port-hdpi/
platform/android/res/drawable-port-ldpi/
platform/android/res/drawable-port-mdpi/
platform/android/res/drawable-port-xhdpi/
```

screen.png,splash.png

Comment: Is your config.xml coherent with those paths? `<platform name="android">
    <splash src="android/res/drawable-port-ldpi-screen/splash.png" density="port-ldpi"/>` for example

Comment: platforms\android\res\xml\config.xml <gap:splash src="splash.png" />
    <gap:splash gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="port-ldpi" src="www/res/screen/android/screen-ldpi-portrait.png" />
    <gap:splash gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="port-mdpi" src="www/res/screen/android/screen-mdpi-portrait.png" />
    <gap:splash gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="port-hdpi" src="www/res/screen/android/screen-hdpi-portrait.png" />
    <gap:splash gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="port-xhdpi" src="www/res/screen/android/screen-xhdpi-portrait.png" />